# pandas groupby/aggregation operation changes 'key' column dtype

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe, aggregate

When I do group and aggregation operation to the original data frame. The dtype of the 'key' is changed from int32 to int64, did I do something wrong here?
Here is a simple example:

```
>df = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.array([3234,332635,325993]), 'amount': np.array([34, 43, 32])})

>df.dtypes

amount    int32
id        int32
dtype: object


>df = df.groupby('id', as_index=False).sum()
>df.dtypes

id        int64
amount    int32
dtype: object
```

Comment: It might be a bug: Usually dtypes should be kept since pandas 0.11 (see https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/2708). In case of your groupby, it seems to "work" when not using as_index=False. Maybe it has something to do with your index being int64 type (`df.index.dtype`).

Comment: I tried to coerce the index dtype to `np.int32` before the group and aggregation, but it did not help, `df.index = df.index.astype(np.int32)`